# Spring boot - file size limits for a custom servlet

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I set upload file size limit for a servlet that has been registered programmatically?

If I use web.xml I would have:

```
 <multipart-config>

      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0<</file-size-threshold>

  </multipart-config>
```

Now I have:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<CXMLServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<XMLServlet>(newXMLServlet(), "*.xml");
}
```

Comment: How about creating a `MultipartConfigElement` (as you would do for a regular config as as well) and set that to the `ServletRegistrationBean` using the `se MultipartConfig` method.

Comment: I think that works.